# I do I resolve the package.jason file error?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Why am I having the below error

```
PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Shareme\shareme_frontend> npm install @sanity/client @sanity/image-url react-google-login react-icons react-loader-spinner react-masonry-css react-router-dom uuid
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: shareme_frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-google-login
npm ERR!   react-google-login@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-29T15_11_18_949Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

react-google-login is not updated to the latest react v18.
Either wait for an update, downgrade react to v17, or use --force flag.

```
npm i react-google-login --force
```

Note that by using --force, there is no guarantee that this package will work with v18 of react

Answer (score 0):

`react-google-login@5.2.2` is not compatible with react 18 version as 5.2.2 is published year ago as per [npm page.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login)

It is still looking for react version of 17 / 16.
Below  error  block will tell you this:

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
```

You can downgrade your react for this specific project via :

1. deleting node_modules
2. run `npm cache clean`
3. manually update your package.json to change version of react to 17
4. run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to install via the command line:

```
npm install @sanity/client @sanity/image-url react-google-login react-icons react-loader-spinner react-masonry-css react-router-dom uui --force
```